# Updated `babel` installation broken: Unhappy about preset(s) configuration?

Tags: babeljs

I recently updated my system and therefore had to reinstall a few tool-chains. This broke my usage of `babel`.

## Before the update (WORKING)

I had `babel` installed as follows ...

```bash
npm install -g babel-cli
npm install -g babel-preset-env
```

... within a Python virtual environment that had `node` integrated via [nodeenv](https://github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv). This would give me `babel` in my `PATH`.

Next, I had a `.babelrc` located in the current working directory with the following content:

```json
{
    "compact": false,
    "presets": [
        [
            "env",
            {
                "targets": [
                    "cover 99.5% in EU",
                    "Firefox ESR",
                    "not ie"
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I would then invoke `babel` as follows:

```bash
babel input.js -o output.js
```

This worked fine with a two to three-ish years old setup. The `.babelrc` file itself is probably even a few years older than that.

## After the update (BROKEN)

I am dealing with:

```
$ babel --version
6.26.0 (babel-core 6.26.3)
$ node --version
v18.8.0
$ npm --version
8.19.1
```

The configuration, the integration via `nodeenv` and the way I invoke `babel` are identical. `babel input.js -o output.js` **fails** as follows:

```
Error: Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory "/working/directory"
    at /env/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:293:19
[...]
```

I tried to make sense of the current documentation on [presets](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/presets), [babel-preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) and [cofiguring babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration), but honestly, I am stuck.

How can I make this work with contemporary `babel` 6?

---

Sorry for a potentially very naive and stupid question question. I rarely work with JS and related tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue actually has multiple layers.

**First problem**: `babel-cli` and `babel-preset-env` are outdated packages. `babel` now uses a different structure, so one must install it instead as follows:

```bash
npm install -g @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env
```

This also implies a change from `"env"` to `"@babel/preset-env"` in the configuration file.

**Second problem**: Although a "global" installation worked before, this is actually something that [babel does not really support](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7381). `babel` will fail to locate `@babel/preset-env`.

There are two things that can be done: Install the three packages mentioned above locally, i.e. without the `-g` flag but instead with `--save-dev`. This dumps everything into the current working directory. If this is not desired, there is an ugly hack: Linking the `node_modules` from within the Python virtual environment into the working directory, i.e.

```bash
ln -s /path/to/python/env/lib64/node_modules node_modules
```

**Third problem**: Outdated configuration. It's details, but the region is now named `alt-EU` instead of `EU`. Besides, `not ie` is not a valid option anymore. `not ie <= 11` is, however. Ultimately, the new configuration has to look as follows:

```json
{
    "compact": false,
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": [
                    "cover 99.5% in alt-EU",
                    "Firefox ESR",
                    "not ie <= 11"
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps someone to NOT burn a crazy amount of time ...